# Axios não consegue pegar dados do meu PHP server

Tags: php, react-native, axios

Estou tentando fazer a conexão entra meu server php e entre o axios .Eu já tinha utilizado o axios porém com node.js.
Estou tentando fazer com que ele puxe os dados do banco e imprima na tela , mas quando eu coloco executo no meu celular ele imprime isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e também é mostrado a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém quando eu acesso no meu navegador ele consegue mostrar os dados no banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o que está havendo ? obrigado!

api.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL : 'http://localhost:3333',
});

export default api;
```

index.js:

```
import React ,{useState , useEffect}from 'react';
import { View , Image , TouchableOpacity ,Text , TextInput} from 'react-native';
import api from '../../services/api';

export default function Teste(){
    const [subs , setSubs] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=> {
        api.get('/substancias').then(resp => {setSubs(resp.data)});
    });

    return(
        <View style={{top : 20 , left : 10}}>
            <Text>{subs.length} , {JSON.stringify(api.get('/substancias').then(resp => resp.data))}</Text>
            {subs.map(e => (
            <Text>{e}</Text>
            ))}
        </View>
    )
};
```

Comment: Mas não entendi pq você colocou na URL o "localhost", servidor não está rodando no celular (localhost significa o próprio dispositivo), então você tem que colocar o IP do servidor. No navegador funcionou pq é a mesma máquina que o servidor está rodando. Além disso, verificar se a porta em questão (3333) está acessível por outros dispositivos na rede.

Comment: entendi , eu fiquei pesquisando mas não encontrei , qual endereço eu devo colocar então dentro da api?? tentei colocar o IPV4 mas msm assim n foi

Comment: Provavelmente a porta 3333 que você usou não está aberta para requisições externas na sua máquina, tente usando a porta 80, normalmente ela está sempre disponível para comunicações HTTP. Uma observação, pelo visto você é bem iniciante em desenvolvimento, se for o caso mesmo, acredito que React Native é um passo muito largo para você agora, procure entender os fundamentos do desenvolvimento de software, React e React Native não é para iniciantes.